# What's the effect by which you represent a "bicolor" screen?

Tags: lighting-effects

If I look at this [picture](https://elementor.com/cdn-cgi/image/f=auto,w=720/marketing/wp-content/uploads/sites/9/2021/11/4-apple-device-from-2010.png) I see a common effect by which a screen is divided into two parts by a slanted line, giving a "shiny glass" effect.

Does this effect/style have a name and any guidelines?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: The word for this is simply "a reflection".  Maybe if you are looking for tutorials you could search for "screen reflection effect". Another similar word might be "glare" - a glare effect.

Comment: Thank you @BillyKerr, that's it! If you want to make your comment an answer, I'll mark it as the accepted one.

Comment: Done, but you don't have to choose my answer as best. Someone else has already given you tips on how you could create it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to lift up the brightness of the dark end of tones and to keep the bright end intact. In the next image it's made by inserting a masked curves adjustment layer in Photoshop. The white area in the mask marks the affected area in the image.

[image]

This simple trick inserted another fake reflection of a window to the left half of the screen. Adjustment layers are not needed. As well one could apply curves to a selection. But adjustment layers don't change the image destructively, one can tweak the effect until it's right.

Answer (score 1):

These are simply called "reflections".  If you are looking for tutorials you could search "screen reflection effect", or possibly also the word "glare". As in, a "screen glare effect".